# EV3 digital interface with sensors?

Tags: ev3

The EV3 Brick is noted as having both analog and a higher speed digital I/O with auto ID up to 460.8 Kbit/s (UART), and 4 motor port with encoders.

The NXT Brick has 4 sensor ports both Analog and Digital: 9600 bit/s (IIC), and 3 motor ports with encoders.

I know the EV3 brick can use NXT sensors and motors, but I cannot find info on the difference in the communication protocol. Are the NXT sensors and motors less precise then the EV3 sensors and motors? Will the EV3 Brick support more sophisticated sensors and motors in the future?
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell much about sensors since the EV3 Hardware Development Kit has not yet been released, but the existing motors have the same precision specifications and are completely interchangeable between NXT and EV3. And yes, hopefully, with the better bandwidth we can expect more sophisticated sensors!
See also http://robotsquare.com/2013/07/16/ev3-nxt-compatibility/